# pick folders from windows path according to date name in java

Tags: java, java-8, directory

I have folders with names as yyyyMMdd format.

For example :

20200813

20200814

20200815

20210813

I need to select latest two folders according its date name. JAVA

Comment: Put them in a list and sort the list.

Comment: Please attach your work

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to get the file listing, sort them *in reverse order* so that the latest file comes first, and then take the first two elements from the list:

```
String directory = ...

List<File> fileList = Arrays.asList(new File(directory).listFiles());

fileList.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());

File latestFile = fileList.get(0);
File secondLatestFile = fileList.get(1);
```